# Retrieving List<> of values for single field in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table called `ProjDetails` which has all the project details, now I want to retrieve the details of all the projects employee was involved.

```
Public EmpProject retrieveProjDetails(int empId, int managerId)
{
    var projDetails = 
    {
        EmpId = empProject.EmployeeId,
        ManagerId = empProject.ManagerId,
        List<projectId> = 
            List<projectName> =
        }
    })
}
```

Here the combination of `EmployeeId` and `ManagerId` can have multiple records and that means multiple project ids, I need to retrieve those all project ids, and then I need to join with another table `Projects` and get the names of those projects based on the project Ids.

Comment: Can you show the three classes involved in your query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can do this:

```
var porjDetails = (from pd in SBDB.ProjDetails   
                   where pd.EmployeeId == empId && pd.ManagerId == managerId              
                   select new EmpProject{
                      EmpId = pd.EmployeeId,
                      ManagerId = empProject.ManagerId,
                      ProjectIds = SBDB.Projects.where(p=>p.ProjectId == pd.ProjectId).Select(p=>p.Id),
                      ProjectNames = SBDB.Projects.where(p=>p.ProjectId == pd.ProjectId).Select(p=>p.Name)
                   });
```

furthermore, i think it's better to have a Projects property, instead of ProjectIds and ProjectNames